# javascript parse weekday value from input type="date"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get values from html input type date and time using javascript and I was wondering if someone can help me to figure out how to parse weekday as well.

Below is what I have so far,

```
function showDate_(getdate) {
    var dateformat = getdate.split('-')
    var displaydate = document.getElementById('time')

    if (displaydate) {
        displaydate.textContent = dateformat[1] + '-' + dateformat[2];
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input onchange="showDate(this.value)" type="date" class="date" />
<div id="time"></div>
```

When selecting the time from calendar, the output will be something like 02-06. How can I include weekday, for example Monday, 02-06?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Hey mate, date will be like ex. mm-dd-yy, you will need all three mandatory, are you sure, you are fetching all three entities of date if yes, then tell me, I can solve

Comment: Hi @rahul_m - Is there anyway I can just fetch mm-dd and also include the weekday? If this is not possible, can you show me the approach you have to parse weekday, mm-dd-yy?

Comment: If the browser supports the `date` input type, it will present a calendar widget and the value will be of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`. You should turn that into an actual `Date` object in your code, after which you can turn it back into a string using any format you like. 

Be aware that not all browsers do support that input type, though, and you should probably have a fallback for those that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
      function showDate(getdate) {
       var selectedDate = new Date(getdate);
       var dateformat = getdate.split('-')
       var displaydate = document.getElementById('time')
       var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    
       if (displaydate) {
        displaydate.textContent = days[selectedDate.getDay()] + ', ' + dateformat[1] + '-' + dateformat[2];
       }
      }
```

```html
 
    
       
    
     <html>
    
    <head><title>Date Example</title></head>
    
    <body>
    
     <input onchange="showDate(this.value)" type="date" class="date" />
     <div id="time"></div>
     
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi @Kush - thanks for the help here, but it doesn't seem the change worked . Can you help again?

Comment: Hi @Codingnewbie - I have included the full code for your reference. and Here is the codepen url - http://codepen.io/KodeK/pen/mRxxPq

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```js
function getDay() {
  const week_of_day_arr = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var dateString = document.getElementById('date').value
  var day = week_of_day_arr[new Date(dateString).getDay()];
  console.log(day);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", getDay)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" placeholder="Enter Date (YYYY-MM-DD)" />
<button id="btn">Get Day</button>
```

to fetch day of week from current date which you will pass.

> your_date_string is your date in the form of yyyy-mm-dd.

Give it a try. It will work.

Comment: Huh, this works even with an abbreviated `dateString` like `2-1`

Comment: Agreed, but just imagine a date with missing of any of dd, mm, yy. Imagined ? And now tell me, can that be correct anyway ?

Comment: @qxz You must be using `Chrome`. It sets default year as `2001`. Try it in Firefox

Comment: @Rajesh True, coincidence that it gave the correct weekday

Comment: @qxz This is 1 big reason why everyone promotes `moment.js`. Every browser has their own implementation for date. This adds lots of patch work and inconsistency in code.

Answer (score 0):

With a given month and day of the month, and assuming the current year, you can use `Date`'s built-in [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function:

```
// returns a number from 0-6 (Sunday-Saturday)
function getDayOfWeek(month, day) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(month-1, day);
  return date.getDay();
}
```

You could convert that index to the day name using a lookup array, as rahul_m shows.